# Spring Boot with H2 is running data.sql every time the web app starts, is this normal?

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have a Spring Boot application with embedded H2 database (configured to save database to disk).

I have a SQL file `data.sql` that creates a `users` table if it doesn't exist, and inserts an `admin` account in the `users` table.

The `data.sql` automatically runs when the app starts up, and everything works fine.

The problem is, it runs `data.sql` every time the application starts and it creates another `admin` record in the `users` table.

QUESTION: How do I configure it so it only runs `data.sql` when the database does not exist yet?

My settings in `application.properties` file look like this, so the data will get saved to disk, and run `data.sql` file to create the database ...

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/myapplication-1.0
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spring Boot with H2 is running data.sql every time the web app starts, is this normal?

**Yes!** it is expected behavior. H2 is designed to load data each time if there exists any `data.sql` file. As because H2 is an inmemory database and expected that data will not persist after the program exit. Thats why data will be loaded each time. If you want some customization either you need to check it programatically or logic should exists(if value exists then update else insert) in `data.sql` file.

There are also easy way, after the data initialization, you set a new configuration value so that data will not loaded from `data.sql` file.

You can use the property `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never` to stop loading database each time.

Reference:
[79.3 Initialize a Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc)